# MySQL process goes over 150% of CPU usage

Tags: mysql

i've seen this topic is discussed extensively in many, many posts, but I would like to know the best solution for this particular issue which my server ran regularly since three months.

VPS Server has 8GB of RAM.

This is a screenshot about top command:

[image: TOP]

The results about mysqltuner:

[image: Mysqltuner]

my.cnf file:

[image: my.cnf]

I've already optimized all my database tables. I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: This is more likely a slow query. Try enabling slow_query_log in my.cnf, check for queries that take long time to finish and then try to optimize them

Comment: Additionally you might consider raising the open files limit - you can check actual usage by calling SHOW STATUS like 'Open_files';  a few times in a row to see how fast the number increases

Comment: Do you have a lot of MyISAM tables? If no it should be safe to decrease the key_buffer_size to 256M or even less, then you might consider increasing sort_buffer_size, read_buffer_size ,read_rnd_buffer_size and join_buffer_size but be carefull because those are allocated for each connection

Comment: Oh - I just noticed you have total 8G RAM but allow mysql to use 9G + at least 256K per connection. This is dangerous and might lead to heavy swapping and data loss

Comment: @DobromirVelev +1 good point, but I don't think swapping is currently his problem, his stats would show higher %sys, while it's 95 %user.  But it will start swapping the minute the DB needs that memory.

Comment: Is your application using persistent connections?

Comment: @HermanB  doesn't "top" take that into account?  Compare the 186% CPU on the mysqld line with the 94% us in the header.  Just checked, it does.

Comment: top actually shows 2.4% memory usage by mysqld, so it is not memory related, there is no iowait so it is not storage related as well. I do wonder what kind of query will use 30-40% cpu or more on a single thread. Try running top -H to get info about each separate mysql thread and run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST to see the queries that are running;

Comment: @DobromirVelev - The "per connection" formula is grossly pessimistic; don't worry.  Do the slowlog.  High CPU is almost always a poorly indexed or formulated query.

Comment: @DobromirVelev When SWAP is 0 as indicated by "top" there will be no swapping, OOM (Out Of Memory) may be frequent.  Red Hat suggests minimum of 20% swap space for predictable reliability - even if slower for a while.

Comment: @i_fiorentino Please consider posting on pastebin.com TEXT results from OS of ulimit -a so we can see the OS limits. Posting the complete MySQLTuner report (after 24 hours of uptime) would include much more information to allow the analysis of likely contributors to your 150 of cpu usage. Also, please post results of iostat -xm 5 3 for indication of Rate Per Second and core count. Please post last 100 lines of your Slow Query Log.  Good to see you back here on SF.

Comment: To monitor open file or open table thrashing, SHOW STATUS LIKE '%open%'; provides both current count and since instance start in the %opened% values.  Get your numbers an hour later and calculate differences to know Rate Per Hour.